# Morphism factoring through a subobject

Tags: ct.category-theory

Van den Berg in his work on predicative topoi says the following:

"Let C be a category. A map f : B → A is a cover, if the only subobject of A through which it factors is A itself."

I have only encountered one morphism factoring another morphism. So I want to check if my understanding is correct. Kind of stringing together the 2 definitions of subobject and factoring through a morphism.

A subobject of C is an isomorphism class of monomorphisms A -> C.
Two morphisms i:A → C, j:B → C are isomorphic if there exists an isomorphism k:a→b such that i=jk.

A morphism f factors through morphism h, if there is a morphism g, such that $f = h \circ g$.

So I would say that morphism f : B -> A factors through a subobject of A, if it factors through some monomorphism C -> A. And factoring only through itself would mean only factoring through the morphisms in the isomorphism class that the identity morphism belongs to and not factoring through any mono within the other classes.

Is this the correct interpretation of a morphism factoring throgh a subobject? What is the correct interpretation?

Comment: Leaving this here as I try to decode it: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/category_theory/subobject/factor_thru.html

Comment: Yes, that is right. In short, a “cover” is a morphism such that it factors through a monomorphism iff the monomorphism is an isomorphism.

Comment: This is the notion of [**factorisation system**](https://ncatlab.org/joyalscatlab/published/Factorisation+systems), where "cover" arises as the orthogonal to the more basic notion of monomorphism.